# How do I return unnamed JSON string array from asp.net mvc2 json result?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following code:

```
var json = MyObject
    .Select(p => new
    {
        id = p.MyObjectId,
        name = p.MyObjectName
    });

return Json(new { json }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This returns a JSON object as follows:

```
{ json: [ { id: 1, name: "Bob" }, { id: 2, name: "Fred" }, { id: 3, name: "James" } ] }
```

However, I need it to return the data as:

```
[ { id: 1, name: "Bob" }, { id: 2, name: "Fred" }, { id: 3, name: "James" } ]
```

Is this possible using the JSON result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```